# Articles: I see you’ve been tucking into the biscuits again, Rob

Tags: grammar, articles, american-english, british-english

This sentence is from [BBC 6 Minute English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/features/6-minute-english/ep-210107).

Neil said: I see you’ve been tucking into the biscuits again, Rob.

Why did he say "the biscuits" ? What's the difference between that and just "biscuits" ?

I thought, if you said "the biscuits", that it would mean that you had eaten the same biscuits that you had eaten in the past.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question! I've been searching several dictionaries and haven't found a general usage of "the" that applies here. There are however some dictionary entries for the word "the" that are similar (in my view) to this instance but, of course, not the same:

From the [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/the):

> used when you are saying what type of musical instrument someone plays
>
> *Lorna plays **the** violin.*

> used before the name of a dish when ordering food, especially in an expensive restaurant
>
> *I’d like **the** salmon, please.*

From [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/the):

> often facetious or derogatory: my; our
>
> ***The** wife goes out on Thursdays.*

As you can see, these definitions (especially the first two) are oddly specific and one would be hard-pressed to expect an English learner to remember them. How these usages came about, I do not know.

When it comes to your sentence in particular, I think it would depend on what Neil means by "the biscuits". I see the word "the" being used here for one of the following reasons:

- to emphasize biscuits in general, in which case you could omit "the" without any problem
- to refer to a particular container (such as a jar) or location in Rob's house which contains biscuits

When I read the sentence, the latter comes to mind, though it could be a stretch depending on who you ask.

In any case, Neil is telling Rob that he notices that Rob looks heavier (i.e. has gained weight) without explicitly saying "Hey, you look fatter than usual." It looks simply like teasing, without any malice involved. The biscuits are mentioned because foods containing lots of calories can contribute to weight gain if eaten frequently, and Neil presumably knows that Rob likes biscuits and attributes Rob's apparent weight gain to eating too many biscuits.

Comment: I got it. Your second reason makes sense to me. Thanks for answering!